# Updating WordPress core with zero downtime - I mean zero

Tags: updates, core, version-control

I have a critical website which is under version control. When I update the core WordPress files I do so locally, then commit the changes. When I do that the live site (obviously) does not even display a maintenance notice, it simply errors out for a few minutes as the core files are deployed, and presumably are either read part way through, or are temporarily incompatible one to the other.

I could update from the live admin, and *then* deploy, which would swap those events around. There *would* be a maintenance notice, and the file incompatibilities would be minimised.

So - question: How could this be accomplished with ZERO downtime? Is there a way? Dual servers with some kind of failover? How do the big companies handle this situation? How can I update the Wordpress core with (literally) zero downtime?

Update: I deploy using a third party SVN provider "[Beanstalk](https://beanstalkapp.com/)", who's own FTP seems to be slow incidentally. But in terms of deployment, even if I FTP the files up from local, there is going to be some downtime. Please regard this question as more of a thought experiment. What is the best approach to updating a WordPress site with ZERO downtime?

Comment: Out of interest. When I deployed the 6.0 update from the previous version, Beanstalk deployed the files and the site was down with a 500 error for 5 minutes.

Comment: can you provide more information about your deployment? Updating WordPress should not take several minutes of time. Additionally, are you sure you can mark an answer as correct? You need to write your questions so that you can mark a single answer as not just _a_ correct answer, but _the_ canonical factual answer that all people should use. I can say already that there are multiple ways that hosting companies manage this, and that there is no one single way to do it

Comment: and judging from your use of the word beanstalk, I presume this is a site hosted on AWS, which is important to know

Comment: Apologies, clarification posted. If we forget "Beanstalk" the fact remains that while older files are overwritten with new ).... sometimes hundreds.... (however that happens) there will be times those files are incompatible and errors occur.

Comment: I understand that, but keep in mind the format of this site requires that you have a specific question that can be answered with hard concrete facts. This isn't a discussion board and open ended questions and discussions don't fit the format. Making your question broader or more abstract does not help that ( broadness and ambiguity is one of the options for voting to close the question ). The only way I see your current situation is to speak with Beanstalk about it, solving this is _highly_ specific to the context situation and host you're using

Comment: E.g. if you wrote an answer that involved creating a new instance with the update, then hotswapping them, then that would be the canonical answer for a small number of users, and impossible for another set of users. You may see it as a canonical answer only to be told that it can't be done by your host, while other users suggest a completely different approach. _There is no one size fits all answer to this._

Comment: I've tried to write an answer, but it's not exactly fulfilling, this is a very broad question that has no canonical answer or solution

Comment: Also, from what I can see Beanstalk isn't so much a hosting service itself as it is a tool, switching to git would produce faster deployments, or using a managed host that handles the WordPress part for you. Their WP deployment guide has tips for entering and leaving maintenance mode while pushing up changes http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploying-wordpress.html

Comment: In AWS we achieve 0 downtime on update using CloudFormation templates with _Auto-scaling Group > Target Group > EC2s_ all behind an ALB. Once the new EC2s and auto-scaling groups are created then we add the target group to the new auto-scaling group then remove the old - you may have a few requests ping between the deployments for 30s or so but the net result is 0 downtime. It's a bit heavy handed for a small deployment though so you may not want to splash out on all that.

Comment: @Bysander - Absolutely fascinating thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There is no general solution to this problem.** Your solution will be specific to your situation, and unusable for many other users, and vice versa. All with their own varying tradeoffs.

For example, some hosting companies spin up new instances with the new update, that then replace the old instances, but this is not possible on many hosts. This also glosses over the fact that what that sentence means can vary wildly depending on the technologies used. For example, a new AWS instance is very different from replacing a container. It's also not going to work for people on shared hosts.

To find a truly concrete answer you will need to work with your host. If their deployment process is not atomic then that's an issue with that host that you need to work with or work around. How you do that is unique to your host and technology stack. The solution for AWS environments for example only works on AWS.

Or you may choose to rely on a cache based system, which only works for certain kinds of sites, and requires additional hardware and software. This might work great for a newspaper for example, but it won't work for a membership site, and has other tradeoffs too.

And for some hosts, usually shared hosts accessed directly, it simply cannot be done as there is no way to bulk update files in one single atomic step. The best they can hope for is a maintenance mode or holding page.

Either way, it's highly dependent on your hosting platform, tech stack, budget, the type of site you have, and commercial needs. *If you constrain this question down to your specific tech stack, there may be a canonical solution*, but it would only apply to users in your specific use case. E.g., there is definitely solutions for AWS/EC2, but it only applies to that particular technology stack.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have ssh access.

The "poor man's solution" would be to create a directory with the new code, e.g. new_code and run

```bash
mv code_dir code_dir_old && ln -s new_code code_dir
```

Which would rename the `code_dir` directory to `code_dir_old` and immediatly after that create a symlink from your prepared new `new_code` directory to `code_dir`.

If you expect database migrations, that only add columns (not remove) then you could run these before making the change.

Comment: I do have SSH, and this type of thing could also be scripted, so thanks for your input!

Comment: A slightly better way would be to have a folder like `wordpress-5.9.3`, and then a `wordpress` symlink that points to `wordpress-5.9.3`. Then when you want to upgrade you run `wp core download --path=wordpress-6.0 && ln -sf wordpress-6.0 wordpress`

Comment: @IanDunn Your `ln` call will put `wordpress-6.0` into `wordpress`, because the latter already exists and is a symlink to a directory (which causes `ln` to change its behaviour to "create symlink inside target directory"). You'll need to add the `-T` parameter to suppress that behaviour.

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks! I thought `-f` took care of that, but it needs to be `ln -sfT wordpress-6.0 wordpress`

Answer (score 4):

[Thomas' answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/406277/873) is good, but repeating it will result in strangely nested directories. I'd like to expand on it to give a full recipe on the poor man's solution using ssh (and also scripts):

One often-used pattern (for a Linux developer) is to create separate directories for each version:

```
wordpress-5.9.2/
wordpress-5.9.3/
wordpress-6.0/
```

and then create one symbolic link to access the "currently active" version (which your web server should use as base directory, a.k.a. document root):

```
ln -s -T -f wordpress-5.9.3 wordpress
```

This gives you the following directory listing:

```
wordpress-5.9.2/
wordpress-5.9.3/
wordpress-6.0/
wordpress -> wordpress-5.9.3
```

Switching between versions then is one command—and you can easily switch back in case of errors:

```
ln -s -T -f wordpress-6.0 wordpress
```

- `-T` tells `ln` to always use the behaviour as if the target was a file, avoiding putting the symbolic link inside a directory if the target is a symbolic link pointing to a directory.
- `-f` overwrites the target if it already exists (instead of throwing an error).
- `-s` just says that it should be a symbolic link instead of a hard link.

Comment: Extremely elegant

Comment: @mayersdesign That's why it's an often-used pattern ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The first step is to use a load balancer. You should have one in any case for any critical site, and have two "application" servers behind it even if you do not expect major traffic spikes, just to have a failover in case of one of the servers failing.

When the time to upgrade comes, you get the server being upgraded off the load balancer, upgrade it (wpcli or direct administrator access via some specific IP address or domain which bypasses the balancer). Once upgraded, you add it back to the balancer and upgrade the other the other application server.

This is not a zero effort solution as it requires some planning regarding image storage, cache clearing and keeping the same DB structure while there is a version mismatch between the application servers.

As someone who had done it, I know it is not "rocket science", but you need to ask yourself if just getting the site offline for an hour (probably much less) every 4 months is such a bad thing that it is worth complicating your site's infrastructure. Do you really need a load balancer just for that reason?

Note regarding deploying from Git or SVN. You should write a script getting WordPress into maintenance mode. Fixing a corrupted DB because some part of the code was on version X while the other was on X+1 can cost you much more than you lose because the site is down for a minute.

Comment: Don't forget to set the "live" database to read-only while the other server is being upgraded. Otherwise you'll have to deal with potential data loss.

Comment: @Plato for  a shop site this will be an equivalent of having the site down. This is why your DB scheme needs to be compatible between old and new version. This do not mean it should be the same, just that a value written in one version will be handled result with the same effect in the other

Answer (score 1):

On my WP host which is a typical VPS where I have root access, I run WP using the official Docker image (`wordpress:fpm`) and an Nginx in front of it. WP files (`wp-content`) are bind-mounted from the host so I can easily manage them.

For a typical WP upgrade, I pull a new Docker image. Then I get rid of the old container and spin up a new one with otherwise identical configuration (networking in particular). This leads to a visible downtime of ~1sec. If I were to achieve zero downtime, I'd spin up the new container alongside the running one, update Nginx config and `nginx -s reload`, let Nginx finish existing connections while new connections are routed to the new PHP FPM container, and only after that do I destroy the old container.

Comment: Absolutely fascinating. This is what I was looking for - real world examples of truly zero downtime, although I accept my question was open-ended - and appreciate the mods leaving it up

Answer (score 0):

personally, I use cache as solution to this

w3 total cache -> page cache activated
solves downtime issues.

but of course, this solution is not perfect for every type of wp site.